# why the last arrow is not placed well?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, positioning

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, latexsym, cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

%DEFINIR COLORES------------------------------------------------------------


\definecolor{verdePortada}{HTML}{25662E}


%DEFINIR ALGUNAS VARIABLES--------------------------------------------------------



\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.5cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm\linewidth]{descarga3.jpg}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1128cm}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to \headwidth{ \color{verdePortada}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
\providecommand{\abs}[2]{\lvert #1\rvert}
\providecommand{\norm}[2]{\lVert #1\rVert}
\begin{document}
Y finalmente, como el seno para ángulos $<$10º se puede sustituir por el ángulo: 
\begin{equation}
  \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{L}\cdot \theta=0  
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
\begin{scope}

  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
 \theta=\theta_{max}\cdot sen(\omega \cdot t+\varphi)
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
\begin{scope}

  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
 \omega=\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
\begin{scope}

  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
 T=\frac{2\cdot \pi}{\omega}
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
\begin{scope}

  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
 T=2\cdot \pi \cdot\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please ask your question in English. Por favor, pregunte en inglés.

Comment: Additionally please complete your code to an example that others can copy and test as is. Secondly, it is not clear from any of the material provided what arrow you are referring to. Might be an idea to make a image where you are _not_ using dark mode

Comment: I'm not sure (a MWE would help), but a guess is that LaTeX is putting the figures at "the most convenient" place. You could force them where you need them with the `float` package.

Comment: it's ok now????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing the `figure` environment, replace `figure` with `center`. The whole point of the `figure` environment is that it can move to ensure better page breaks, i.e. avoiding large blank spaces at end of a page. This is a case where you don't want the contents to float, and you have no intention of adding a caption, so `figure` is the wrong environment to use.

However, I'd probably use a single `gather` environment (from the `amsmath` package), and add the arrows on a separate line with `\nonumber` instead. Both are demonstrated in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% create a custom command for the arrow, so you don't have to repeat 
% everything every time
% \tikz is a shortform for \begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\MyDownarrow{\tikz\draw[-latex, thick] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);}

\begin{document}

\section{I'd do this instead}
Y finalmente, como el seno para ángulos $<$10º se puede sustituir por el ángulo: 
\begin{gather}
  \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{L}\cdot \theta=0  \\
  \MyDownarrow \nonumber \\
 \theta=\theta_{\mathrm{max}}\cdot \operatorname{sen}(\omega \cdot t+\varphi) \\
 \MyDownarrow \nonumber \\
 \omega=\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}} \\
 \MyDownarrow \nonumber \\
  T=\frac{2\cdot \pi}{\omega} \\
 \MyDownarrow \nonumber \\
  T=2\cdot \pi \cdot\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}
\end{gather}


Para ángulos $>$10º se usa el desarrollo de taylor del seno.

\section{But just replacing figure with center and removing the scopes}


Y finalmente, como el seno para ángulos $<$10º se puede sustituir por el ángulo: 
\begin{equation}
  \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{L}\cdot \theta=0  
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{equation}
 \theta=\theta_{\mathrm{max}}\cdot \operatorname{sen}(\omega \cdot t+\varphi)
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{equation}
 \omega=\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{equation}
 T=\frac{2\cdot \pi}{\omega}
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.4);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{equation}
 T=2\cdot \pi \cdot\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}
\end{equation}


Para ángulos $>$10º se usa el desarrollo de taylor del seno.
\end{document}
```

[image]